# How to use global variable in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, global

this code

```
class CircumstancesController extends AppController {
public $circumstances = array();
public function init() {
        $this->circumstances = $this->getAllCircumstance();

    }

    //get all circumstances
    public function getAllCircumstance() {
        $arr_allcircumstance = $this->Circumstance->find('all', array(
            'recursive' => -1
        ));
        return $arr_allcircumstance;
    }
    public function getCircumstances($circumstance) {
        $arr_cir = $this->circumstances;

        return $arr_cir;
    }
    public function data_matrix() {
        pr($this->getCircumstances(3));

    }
}
```

i had a variable "$circumstances"(type array) when i call function data_matrix() then function result is  NULL.

```
$arr_cir = $this->circumstances;
```

why $arr_cir is null ???
thank all.

Comment: Your question does not seem very clear to me.

Comment: this is not a Cakephp controller ..

Comment: it is cakephp controller

Comment: Obviously either `init()` is never invoked, or `getAllCircumstance()` returns `null` - so, do some debugging!

Answer (score 1):

public $circumstances = array();

Because this is a empry array that why it's return empty

```
public $circumstances = array(3,5);
```

Please use this and check

Comment: but i had $this->circumstances = $this->getAllCircumstance(); to get data from database.

Comment: so assign value in $this->circumstances otherwise it's alway get empty

Answer (score 0):

push some values into array.. and after debug() or print it to exactly view the array values. try it .

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename your init() function to beforeFilter().

[BeforeFilter documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3abeforeFilter)